# How to check if a PHP class has a parent (Also it extends another)?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, extend

I am trying to check if my PHP class is extending another class. I am able to retrive the class itself with `get_parent_class()` but when checking if that is null it's just throwing a null pointer exception.

I want to get a boolean that is true if the class is extended. Thereby avoiding the null pointer exception.

Comment: I doubt it helps your problem, but get_parent_class() returns false if no parent is found, not null. Might be worth checking.

Comment: Can you see the code of the class?

Comment: Thanks, that it returns false helped alot. Seems like there is lacking documentation for this at php.net.

I was able to add a check before actually constructing the class.

Comment: PHP has "null pointer exceptions"?!

Answer (score 4):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-parents.php

> An array on success, or FALSE on error.

```
function hasParents($object) {
    $parents = class_parents($object);
    return is_array($parents) && !empty($parents);
}
```

**UPD.:** simplified way

```
function hasParents($object) {
    return (bool)class_parents($object);
}
```

https://extendsclass.com/php-bin/dfa71d0

Comment: `return (bool)class_parents($object);` – keep it simple, please.

Comment: Or, a little more readable: `return class_parents($object) !== false`.

Comment: @Franz That is not true. A class without any parents will return `[]`, not `false`.

Comment: True. I guess a `!=` would do.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just use `get_parent_class()`, can't you?

Comment: @shaedrich it's written in question that person could not get result with `get_parent_class` method, so I've wrote alternatives. but of course `get_parent_class` should work, but strange that it's throwing null pointer exception.

Comment: @num8er Oh, my bad. Yeah, that is strange. I'd have assumed, they work quite similar 

Answer (score 0):

`is_subclass_of()` function does the job:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php

Wisely it accepts not only class instance but also class name - no object creation needed to get the information.